# Dynamic AVG in MDX

Tags: excel, ssas, mdx, powerbi, cube

How can I calculate `AVG` of many members?

Let's assume that I have measure Risk. I am interested only in average risk, across many dimensions. Users:

1.Connect to cube from Excel and if they choose measure Avg Risk, they want to see average risk for selected dimensions.

2.They also want to use it in Power BI.

For that reason I look for dynamic member, that I can use in following formula:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Avg Risk] AS  
   Avg(  
      Dynamic member,   
      [Measures].[Risk] 
   )
```

to achieve this behavior. 
Is it possible?

Comment: rather than "Dynamic member" you'll need "Dynamic set" as a set is the first argument required for the Avg function. How to do this I'm unsure although I wish you good luck in implementing in PowerBI - when I played with that tool a few months back it seemed a bit rigid for surfing olap cubes

Comment: Let's say the user filters to a slice of the cube which has 100 rows. Would the sum of the risk column divided by 100 be the correct average? If you want a row level average please let us know. If not please provide a more detailed example.

Comment: Exactly, I would like to sum one measure (in context of returned rows) and divide it by number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create two new real measures in your cube structure. Set the first measure to aggregation "Sum" of your desired column which you use for your risk measure. Set the second measure to aggregation "Count of rows" or "Count of non-empty values" of the same column.

Second create a new calculated measure with the following mdx statement:

```
divide([Measures].[Created SUM measure], [Measures].[Created Count measure])
```

This is the standard to calculate averages in ssas.